# How to delete same numbers and shift the array to delete them in c

Tags: c

I have been trying to solve this problem, but to no avail. I have one array and would like to delete the re-occurring values that are next to each other only. Later I want to resize the array to get rid of these values.

This is the initial array:

```
A[] = {1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

This is what it should look like in the end result

```
A[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

This is the code I have been playing with. There seems to be a major logical flaw in this... As a post below suggested I am trying to put the different values in another array.

```
int A[]= {1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int B[20];
int indexB = 0;

int main()
{
   for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
   {
       if(A[i] != B[indexB] ){
        B[indexB] = A[i];

        if(A[i+1] != B[indexB] ){
            indexB++;
        }
       }
   }


   printf("%d \n", indexB); // Printing how many values the new array would have

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far / where you are stuck https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: First of all you need to realize that once an array is defined, its size is fixed. There's no way to resize an array.

Comment: As for the problem of "removing" or "erasing" consecutive duplicates, there's plenty of resources and examples if you just search a little. A simple one is to copy the array to itself, element by element, skipping the copying if the previous element is equal to the current. Once you reach the end fill the rest with zeros (or other suitable values).

Comment: *"I have been trying to solve this problem"* - your question should include closest-to-success attempt, and what steps you've taken thus far to debug the problem(s)

Comment: You can't resize an array.
You can (as an example) go over it, overwrite the repeating number with the next one in the list  and fill the "removed" spaces with zeros then copy the content to a new array of desired size. But we are not going to write code for you if you don't show what you tried and why it's not working.

Comment: @WhozCraig The other attempts were too messy, that is why I refrained from uploading them, but this is what I am currently working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
int A[]= {1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int B[20];
int indexB = 0;
int i;

 int main()
{
   for (i = 0;i <= 7;++i)
   {
       if(A[i] != A[i+1]){
           B[indexB++] = A[i];
       }
       else {
           continue;
        }
    }

B[indexB++] = A[i];

printf("%d \n", indexB); // Printing how many values the new array would have

return 0;
}
```

This should work and fill B with the array without the duplicates

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but with this method I get that the new array would have 5 values, when it is meant to have 7 values

Comment: @frankmitchelle actually that returned 6 not 5. it's fixed now, i forgot about the last number since it's not inserted because we would go beyond the array size with the check. There's probably a much better way to do it but this is what i came up on the spot making it similar to what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Simple basic solution is,
When you want to removing the consecutive duplicates,

- Iterate the array one by one
- And copy the element to the another array only if,
- The current element is not as same as the previous one.

Comment: I am trying that, but it seems I have a logical flaw somewhere in my code. I attached it to my question. Maybe you can spot the mistake I made, as I cannot :(